# Cognos download charts in a report

Tags: cognos

I am trying to use the 'download chart' option which is seen when we right click on the chart in a cognos viewer. When I click this option it shows the 'webpage cannot be diplayed' message. I am using 10.2 version of cognos. Is there something which needs to be enabled in the report to download charts.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see the URL of the page when it gives you the webpage cannot be displayed message?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I see the URL of the page when it gives the "webpage cannot be displayed message". But it is inserted between an XSSTART and XSSEND as XSS filtering option is enabled in our cognos configuration. Do you think this might be the issue..The URL looks something like this below 
xssstarthttp://servername/ibmcognos/cgi-bin/cognos.cgi?REMAINING URL&download=trueXSSEND

Thanks.